# is not abstract and does not override abstract method OnPreferenceChange(Preference,Object)

Tags: android

I want to register a list preference's preference changes like so

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;

public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    ListPreference mListPreferece;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_prefs);

        String preferenceName = getString(R.string.list_pref);
        mListPreferece = (ListPreference) findPreference(preferenceName);

        mListPreferece.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                new android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        System.out.print(newValue.toString());
                        return false;
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

I appear to be overriding the interface method properly, yet I'm receiving this error

> [My Fragment] is not abstract and does not override abstract method OnPreferenceChange(Preference,Object)

This is the line that causes the error

```
new android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, show the class and method which contains this code.

Comment: Do you use support preferences? Because it seems to me from the fully qualified package name that you use some kind of a `Preference` somewhere else, which is support prefs I guess.

Comment: Added packages and class in edit @GergelyKőrössy

Comment: You are mixing support classes and native classes. You should use one or the other.

Comment: I have edited your question so that the imports and class are in the actual code example. Please edit `SOMEMETHOD()` to show the actual method name where this code is. Is it supposed to be `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Okay done @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {` @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay, stupid mistake I guess, see my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the support and the framework `Preference` classes. The former is available under `android.support.v7.preference.Preference` while the latter is `android.preference.Preference`. You cannot mix these as both of them expect an `OnPreferenceChangeListener` from their packages. Now you have a choice: use either the framework one or the support one.

#### Option 1 - Framework classes

Use this if the rest of your app uses [`android.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) classes (so the framework ones). In this case you'd have to change the import statement of the `Preference` class from

```
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
```

to

```
import android.preference.Preference;
```

#### Option 2 - Support classes (v14)

If your app uses the framework fragments, but you want to use the support library's preferences, you'd have to change the import mainly from

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```

Then remove the fully qualified package name from the new instance of the preference change listener so you'll use the support [`OnPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html):

```
mListPreferece.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
        new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                System.out.print(newValue.toString());
                return false;
            }
});
```

#### Option 3 - Support classes (v7)

If your app uses the support fragments (instances of [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)), you'd need to change a few things in your preferences.

First of all remove the fully qualified package name from the new instance of the preference change listener so you'll use the support [`OnPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html):

```
mListPreferece.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
        new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                System.out.print(newValue.toString());
                return false;
            }
});
```

In this case you'll also need to use [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) instead of the `PreferenceFragment` you use now, so change

```
public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragment
```

to

```
public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
```

---

> **Note** that both support versions requires you to use `onCreatePreferences(...)` for inflating the preferences XML instead of `onCreate(...)`.

---

**P.S.:** If you want to use the support v7 option, I'd recommend my [library fix](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) that solves a couple common bugs / problems with the official implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
```

to

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```

Comment: I think you must have changed it to `android.preference.Preference`.

Answer (score -1):

OnPreferenceChangeListener is an interface, not a class, so it needs to be implemented, usually by an activity or fragment, rather than instantiated.

Try something more like this (not runnable code!):

```
public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
    implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(
         Preference preference, Object newValue) {
         System.out.print(preference.getKey().toString());
         if ( /* preference.getKey() is preferenceName */ ) {
             System.out.print(newValue.toString());
             return false;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mListPreferece.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: This is not the core issue. Creating an anonymous inner class is a feasible alternative to implementing the interface.